# Group union query by column in SQL

Tags: sql

I'm querying 2 tables with a union:

```
select date, A, B 
from table1 
where SERIAL_NUMBER = 1234
  and date > 'Sep 10 2018' 
  and date < 'Sep 20 2018' 

union 

select date, C, D 
from table2
where SERIAL_NUMBER = 1234
  and date > 'Sep 10 2018' 
  and date < 'Sep 20 2018' 
order by date
```

This results in something like:

```
date1 a1 b1
date1 c1 d1
date2 a2 b2
date2 c2 d2
```

But I want something like:

```
date1 a1 b1 c1 d1
date2 a2 b2 c2 d2
```

Is this possible?

Comment: . . You should tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Then you would seem to want `join`:

```
select t1.date, t1.a, t1.b, t2.c, t2.d
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.date = t2.date and t1.serial_number = t2.serial_number
where t1.SERIAL_NUMBER = 1234 and t1.date > '2018-09-10' and t1.date < '2019-09-20'
order by t1.date;
```

Depending on how you want to deal with missing dates, you might want a `full join` instead of `inner join`.

Also note that I changed the date format to YYYY-MM-DD.  That is a standard format recognized by most databases.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't need to use `UNION ALL`, use `JOIN` instead of that.

```
select t1.date, t1.A, t1.B ,t2.C, t2.D 
from table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 on t1.date = t2.date
where t1.SERIAL_NUMBER = 1234
and t1.date > 'Sep 10 2018' 
and t1.date < 'Sep 20 2018'
```